# Joiner or lookup which is best to perform left join

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

My source1 has 100 records and source2 has 1M records and i want perform left join . Which one you prefer Joiner transformation or lookup transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer lookup.
So you have below options based on your scenario/data -

1. if source 1 is in same database - try left joining in db itself in source qualifier. but you need to check the join condition and relationship.
2. if source 1 is not in same database -
   2.1 use joiner - if you join on unique key and if you want many columns from source.
   2.2 use lookup - if you do not have unique key to join and many-many relation exists between them.

Performance wise, option 1 will be better than option 2. Option 2.2 will be better than 2.1 because in 2.2, you have to cache only small table and joiner will cache complete data.

Comment: suppose if my source is 1M i want to join. which is good Joiner or LKP. what are the drwabacks if i use joiner instead of LK and Vice versa

Comment: preferable lkp if you think about better performance. Joiner - data should be joined on unique keys or there shouldnt be many to many relationships. joiner caches all data so its slower. Lkp - data need not be unique.  lkp only cache lkp table/file so its faster.